# How to get Ember Data's "store" from anywhere in the application so that I can do store.find()?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

With the recent [update](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#elimination-of-modelfind-and-modelcreaterecord), I know that in routers and controllers, I can easily just do `this.store.find('model')`.  However I have some functions that need to call `find` that are not in routers and controllers. So how can I get an instance `store` from anywhere in an Ember App?

I know worst comes to worst I can do `App.__container__.lookup('store:main')`, but I'll try to stay away from that.

Answer (score 10):

The [TRANSITION](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md) doc says that you can do this to inject the store into components :

```
App.inject('component', 'store', 'store:main');
```

You might be able to change `'component'` to `'view'` or to `'model'`, but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 7):

You can do

```
App.Model.store.find('model')
```

If you have a particular attribute to filter with, you can do:

```
App.Model.store.find('model', {'attribute_name' : 'matching_to_this_value'})
```

[See more on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18768501/733034).

Comment: Just for clarity, that's if your model class is `Model`...or if your model was `Post`, then `App.Post.store.find('post')`. This is probably frowned upon but it works great for me!

Answer (score 7):

You can try to do

```
this.get('controller').get('store').find('model')
```

That would wok in a View for example.

Answer (score 1):

With Ember Data `1.0.0-beta.X`:

```
App.YourModelType.store.find("yourModelType", someId).then( 
  function(modelInstance) { 
  ...
  });
```