# Create / Update multiple objects from one API response

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

**all new jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vJxvc/2/**

Currently, i query an api that will return JSON like this. The API cannot be changed for now, which is why I need to work around that.

```
[
    {"timestamp":1406111961, "values":[1236.181, 1157.695, 698.231]},
    {"timestamp":1406111970, "values":[1273.455, 1153.577, 693.591]}
]
```

*(could be a lot more lines, of course)*

As you can see, each line has a timestamp and then an array of values. My problem is, that i would actually like to transpose that. Looking at the first line alone:

```
{"timestamp":1406111961, "values":[1236.181, 1157.695, 698.231]}
```

It contains a few measurements taken at the same time. This would need to become this in my ember project:

```
{
    "sensor_id": 1,    // can be derived from the array index
    "timestamp": 1406111961,
    "value": 1236.181
},
{
    "sensor_id": 2,
    "timestamp": 1406111961,
    "value": 1157.695
},
{
    "sensor_id": 3,
    "timestamp": 1406111961,
    "value": 698.231
}
```

And those values would have to be pushed into the respective sensor models.

The transformation itself is trivial, but i have no idea where i would put it in ember and how i could alter many ember models at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

you could make your model an array and override the `normalize` method on your adapter. The `normalize` method is where you do the transformation, and since your json is an array, an Ember.Array as a model would work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a ember pro but looking at the [manual](http://emberjs.com/guides/enumerables/) I would think of something like this:

```
a = [
    {"timestamp":1406111961, "values":[1236.181, 1157.695, 698.231]},
    {"timestamp":1406111970, "values":[1273.455, 1153.577, 693.591]}
];

b = [];

a.forEach(function(item) {
  item.values.forEach(function(value, sensor_id) {
      b.push({
         sensor_id: sensor_id,
         timestamp: item.timestamp,
         value: value
      });
  });
});

console.log(b);
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/kRUV4/

**Update**

Just saw your jsfiddle... You can geht the store like this: [How to get Ember Data's "store" from anywhere in the application so that I can do store.find()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753768/how-to-get-ember-datas-store-from-anywhere-in-the-application-so-that-i-can-d)